# Hibernate mapping - map through table

Tags: java, hibernate, dictionary, many-to-many

I have the following database structure:

```
Table 1                    Table 2 
                                                       Table 3
tid_1 ----(many-to-one)---- tid_1                        
....                        tid_2 ----(one-to-many)---- tid_2
                                                        tkey
                                                        tvalue
```

Is there a way to create a class, defined by `Table 1`, with `java.util.Map`, associating `tkey` with `tvalue` from `Table 3`? I'm pretty new to Hibernate, and, before asking, I've tried to search and experiment, but got nothing. Any help will be appreciated.

P.S.
If this will not obstruct you, I'd prefer using `.hbm.xml` style.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can declare a map with `tkey` as a key and an entity mapped to `Table 3` as a value:

```
@Entity
public class Table1 {
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "Table2")
    @MapKey(name = "key")
    private Map<String, Table3> table3s;

    ...
}

@Entity
public class Table3 {
    @Column(name = "tkey")
    private String key;

    @Column(name = "tvalue")
    private String value;

    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, if I get it right, in such manner benefits of using a map will be lost - values will not be accessible through keys

Comment: @Frozen: You can always do `table3s.get(key).getValue()`.

Comment: You could also write a getter on Table1 which returns a map which wraps the table3s property and gives the illusion of a `Map<String, String>`. It takes a considerable amount of boilerplate, but isn't hard to do. You could use [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)'s [Maps.transformValues](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release08/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Maps.html#transformValues%28java.util.Map,%20com.google.common.base.Function%29) to make it a bit simpler (but possibly read-only).